# GWT DockLayoutPanel blank page

Tags: gwt, errai

I'm trying to use DockLayoutPanel in Jboss-errai application. 
My entry point class:

```
@EntryPoint
public class Application {

private Caller<UserService> userService;

private Label registerConfirmMessage;

@AfterInitialization
public void createUI() {

    DockLayoutPanel p = new DockLayoutPanel(Unit.EM);
    p.addNorth(new HTML("header"), 2);
    p.addSouth(new HTML("footer"), 2);
    p.addWest(new HTML("navigation"), 10);
    p.add(new HTML("content"));
    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(p);
}
```

My Application.gwt.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 2.4//EN"
    "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/releases/2.4/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">

<!-- GWT module definition: the rename-to attribute is used to have a shorter 
module name that doesn't reflect the actual package structure. -->
<module>
 <inherits name="org.jboss.errai.common.ErraiCommon" />
 <inherits name="org.jboss.errai.bus.ErraiBus" />
 <inherits name="org.jboss.errai.ioc.Container" />
 <inherits name="org.jboss.errai.enterprise.CDI" />
 <inherits name="org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator" />

 <source path="client" />   
 <source path="shared" />
</module>
```

I detected different result when I change DOCTYPE. So:

In IE6 it works with either doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

Blank page in Mozilla Firefox 14, Chrome

```
<!DOCTYPE>
```

Blank page in FF14, but it works in Chrome.

All other doctypes result in blank page.

Advise me please correct solution!

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> This widget will only work in standards mode, which requires that the
>   HTML page in which it is run have an explicit  declaration.

So that means that:

1.The browser needs to be running in standards mode, and not in quirks mode.

2.In the beginning of your HTML file you should have this:

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- The DOCTYPE declaration above will set the     -->
<!-- browser's rendering engine into                -->
<!-- "Standards Mode". Replacing this declaration   -->
<!-- with a "Quirks Mode" doctype is not supported. -->
```

The doctype is defined in the HTML page where the application starts.

and not the gwt.xml

Also check the the link below, it describes how a gwt project is organized:

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects

Comment: Thanks. It partly helps me. But now I have another problem with height. Do I needs to assign height of some panels (RootLayoutPanel, DocsLayoutPanel)? I'd like to have 100% screen height of my DockLayoutPanel.

Comment: When you are adding east, north, west, and south, you should add the size (height for north/south and width for east/west), center should always be added in the end, and it takes all remaining space. For example, if you just add a button in the center then it should take up all the space

Comment: Yes, I did it as you wrote. I think I found a solution with css: html, body { height: 100%; }